# How to visualize the results from A/B testing as soon as possible in the reporting?

Tags: personalization, reporting

I'm setting up some local development tests to properly validate the functionality of AB Page- and Component tests.

I'm using the /admin/kill.aspx page to succesfully kill a session. I can see data in the Mongo after visiting that page.

Now I want to force the reporting screen to update as soon as possible. Like this one:

[image]

**Does anyone have an idea which timeout value and in which config file I must make the necessary changes?**

Sitecore version 8.2 Update 3

Comment: I have to dig into it, but I think you have to wait until the analytics index runs. Which I think is every 10 minutes by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These reports are made from the aggregated xdb data.

You can tweak the aggregation and processing intervals to make sure your data is put to the reporting database more frequently. You need to alter the following setting value for aggregation agents: `<Interval>0.00:00:15</Interval>`

Please refer to this guideline from official Sitecore documentation: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_agreggation_agents

However, do note that the more frequently it runs, the bigger is the performance impact (and even more on high load solutions)